# WCF WPF Web Service Client throwing 404

Tags: wpf, wcf, web-config, client, endpoint

I know there is a lot of question about the problem with that error but I can not get out of it .

When I wrote  the adress in navigator it's work but when I call the same method in my WPF Application I have the 404 error.

Here it's my servicemode of my WPF Application :

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webEndpoint">
      <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped"
               defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml"
               helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
 <bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttp">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
 <client>
  <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="webHttp"
            behaviorConfiguration="webEndpoint"  
            contract="ServiceReferenceBX.IServiceBX"
            address="http://localhost:9804/ServiceBX.svc">
  </endpoint>
 </client>
</system.serviceModel>`
```

This is my web.config of my WCF

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
<httpModules>
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
</httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="BXSportWCFLib.ServiceBX" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
    <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="BXSportWCFLib.IServiceBX" behaviorConfiguration="web">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
    preCondition="managedHandler"/>
</modules>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>`
```

Here is my Contract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceBX
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        UriTemplate = "ListExercices/{guidUser}")]
    List<Exercice> getListExercices(string guidUser);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    Exercice AddNewExercice(string guidUser,string nom,bool nbRepetition, bool Poids, bool Distance, bool Duree);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        UriTemplate = "ListeFen/{guidUser}")]
    List<Fenetre> getFenetres(string guidUser);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        UriTemplate = "Connect/{login}/{mdpCrypt}")]
    string UserConnect(string login, string mdpCrypt);

}
```

I made my test with the method UserConnect.

Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
  <section name="BXSportCL.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="soap" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="1116553600"
             maxBufferPoolSize="1116553600"
             maxBufferSize="1116553600"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="mex" maxReceivedMessageSize="1116553600"
             maxBufferPoolSize="1116553600">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:9804/ServiceBX.svc/soap"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="soap" contract="ServiceReferenceBX.ServiceBX"
    name="soap" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
<applicationSettings>
<BXSportCL.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="DebugMode" serializeAs="String">
    <value>True</value>
  </setting>
</BXSportCL.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here my web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>

<connectionStrings>
<add name="ModelBXContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelBX.csdl|res://*/ModelBX.ssdl|res://*/ModelBX.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=GOBELET-PC\SQLEXPRESS;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<httpModules>
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
</httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="BXSportWCFLib.ServiceBX" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint name="rest" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="BXSportWCFLib.ServiceBX" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" />
    <endpoint name="mex" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="BXSportWCFLib.ServiceBX" />
    <endpoint name="soap" address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="BXSportWCFLib.ServiceBX" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior" >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restBehavior">
      <webHttp  />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And here is my contract :

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "ServiceBX", Namespace = "http://ServiceBX/", SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
//[ServiceKnownType(typeof (IList<MyDataContractTypes>))]
[ServiceBehavior(Name = "ServiceBX", Namespace = "http://ServiceBX/")]
public class ServiceBX
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "Fenetres")]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Fenetres/{guidUser}")]
    public string getFenetres(string guidUser)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DAL.User.getFenetres(guidUser), settings);
        //return SerialJSON.WriteFromObject(DAL.User.getFenetres(guidUser),typeof(List<Fenetre>));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: I don't know what write more, I changed all my code.

Comment: You got things working, and that's great. But this is your chance to help future users with similar problems. So could you explain things like: What have you changed? What was wrong with the old code? How do the changes address those specific problems? That way, others may be able to learn from it to solve their problems.